# TypeScript override existing package interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-module-resolution

How can I override existing interface property from package?

This is in the package:

```
   // in one file .d.ts
    export interface LDProps {
        flags?: LDFlagSet;
        ldClient?: LDClient;
    }

   // in other file .d.ts
    declare module 'module-name' {
       ...
       export interface LDFlagSet {
           [key: string]: LDFlagValue;
       }
       ...
    }
```

I want to override `LDFlagSet` properties. I do not want it to be key: string. I have my specific keys.

What I tried:

```
declare module 'module-name' {
    interface LDFlagSet {
        param1: boolean
    }
}

// obj.param1 should be valid
// obj.random should not be valid
```

Now my intellisense shows me that param1 exist with type boolean. But it allows me any other key: string with type any. **I want only my properties to be valid.**

How I can do that?

Comment: You could only widen existing third-party interfaces. So you should create wrapper/helper function that casts one type to another

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue without undeclared types or values.  I doubt you can do anything here except for using a local fork of the third party package d.ts files.  You can't use declaration merging in all circumstances (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40904 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19064 and probably a lot more).  I can write up an answer if that addresses your question; otherwise, what am I missing?